React Native Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. in JavaScript map function
I am not able to get rid of it with this warning
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Here is the complete code:
const App = () => {

  const userList = [
    {
      key: 1,
      name: "Amit"
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      name: "Ajit"
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      name: "Avinash"
    },
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Hello List</Text>
      <ScrollView>
        {
          userList.map((item) => <Text style={styles.container}>{item.name}</Text>)
        }
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};


It says what you have to do right there in the warning.
Add a key property to the <Text you return in the map. For example,
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Hello List</Text>
      <ScrollView>
        {
          userList.map((item) => <Text key={item.name} style={styles.container}>{item.name}</Text>)
        }
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );

